# Android Save dynamically added text grid view

Tags: android, listview, gridview, save

I implemented this example into my project:

http://camposha.info/source/aandroid-data-passing-from-textbox-to-second-activity

So, and now I want to save the text, I've added through the edittext. Is this possible?

Or can I change the grid view with list view? I want to enter text and the text will be displayed on second activity. If it's in a grid view or list view . I don't know if it's possible to do that with list view. If so, please help me :)

I am beginner, so thanks for helping.

Gustav

Answer (score 0):

> I want to save the text, I've added through the edittext. Is this possible?

Yes, You can use `SharedPreferences`, `SQLite Database` and other ways. I suggest you read this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/) which completely explains how to preserve data in android. You can modify `DataHolder` class, so this class can save and load data from one of these storage, and use it to save texts in `MainActivity` and load them in `SecondActivity`.

And I did not understand the second part of your question! Do you want to show data in a `ListView` instead of `GridView`? If so, then you can replace that `GridView` with a `ListView` in `ActivitySecond.xml` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.tutorials.hp.txttoactivitygrid.SecondActivity">
    <!-- Replace with this -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And then in your `SecondActivity.java` replace `GridView gv;` with `ListView ls;` and then change

```
gv= (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gv);
gv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, DataHolder.spacecrafts));
```

with

```
lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, DataHolder.spacecrafts));
```

The idea is to replace every code which uses `GridView` to use `ListView` instead .I think this modification is enough and should work. If it doesn't let me know so I can help you.
Also you can read about `ListView` and how to use it [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_list_view.htm). (You can find lots of tutorials when you search for it on the internet :D)

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your answer! I found this link you recommend me: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences You said, I should modify the DataHolder Class. So I can put that code into DataHolder Class? And I want to save and load the text from Second activity. Main activity is only tipping text in and send it to second activity. But maybe I can save all input text from edittext and load it together in second activity? Is it easier to save list view? Then I would change Grid view to listview. Can I save listview like Grid view with SharedPreferences? Thank you :)

Comment: I suggest you use `SQLite` for storing texts since you have a list of texts and `SharedPreferences` not designed for this kind of situations (Well there are ways to do that but `SQLite` is designed for this). Just create a table and store all the text in it and then load them wherever you want I can put up a sample on how to do it if I get free time. But I suggest you try to do it yourself first as an exercise since it can help you to learn better! And yes, You can save `ListView`'s data like `GridView`.

Comment: Okay, I will do it, when I am home, so in 3 days. I will replace Grid view with list view and save list view with sqlite. I will search for some examples and otherwise I didn't have any idea I will ask you.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help. It's all working. 
But when I add an item to listview and go back to fragment where listview is in I have to switch to another fragment and go back for showing the before added item. Is there a possibility to refresh listview view directly? Thanks

Comment: Hello. hmmm...maybe you forgot to call `notifyDataSetChanged` on your list view's adapter after adding new item so you list can update itself? something like this `listView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged()`